# how can I remove the color point from DrawNode in cocos2dx, but I don't want to removeChild from parent. Just remove some point of it

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I add a   drawNode child in my code And use one child to draw many points.Then how can  I   remove the point form the drawNode just remove point and keep the drawNode in here.

```
    auto m_pDrawPoint = DrawNode::create();
    this->addChild(m_pDrawPoint);                   
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      m_pDrawPoint->drawPoint(screenP[i], 20, Color4F::GREEN);

    }
     // I  want remove some of  point Like remove the screenP[3]
```

Comment: What have you done? Add at least a snippet code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `clearPoint` in cocos2d-x. When `DrawNode::drawPoint` is called, the drawNode just save the position, point size and color on a bare array. And you have no access to this array unless you overwrite `DrawNode`. If you want to clear some points, using `DrawNode::clear` to remove points and then redrawing the points you need would be a good idea.

//Edit

```
    auto m_pDrawPoint = DrawNode::create();
    this->addChild(m_pDrawPoint);                   
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      m_pDrawPoint->drawPoint(screenP[i], 20, Color4F::GREEN);
      m_points.push_back(screenP[i]);
    }

void Foo::removePoint(const Vec2& point){
    for(int i=0; i<=m_points.size(); i++){
        if(point==m_points[i]){
            //this is a trick
            m_points[i] = m_points[m_points.size()];
            m_points.pop_back();
            break;
        }
    }
    m_pDrawPoint.drawPoints(m_points.data(), m_points.size(),20, Color4F::GREEN);
}
```

Subclassing DrawNode seems more simpler.

```
class MyDrawNode: public DrawNode{
public:
    void removePoint(const Vec2& point){
        for(int i=0; i<_bufferCountGLPoint; i++){
            V2F_C4B_T2F *p = (V2F_C4B_T2F*)(_bufferGLPoint + i);
            // point==p->vertices doesn't work as expected sometimes.
            if( (point - p->vertices).lengthSquared() < 0.0001f ){
                *p = _bufferGLPoint + _bufferCountGLPoint - 1;
                _bufferCountGLPoint++;
                break;
            }
        }
    };

};
```

Comment: Is there good idea for me to draw some points and remove  and draw again. And I don't want to add to much more child. should I use openGL to    draw point. Is a good ?

Comment: Even using opengl, you still need to store all these points. Don't worry, you can just add one time member variable `vector<Vec2> m_pointsToDraw`.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you have many DrawNodes, using `unorder_map<DrawNode*, vector<Vec2> >` is better. Be careful that the key may be dangling pointer. @snowlyCoding